# Navigating Sliders in style bar on Webflow

Tags: webflow

I’ve recently started learning the Webflow platform and have run into a small roadblock. I’m using this cloneable theme: [CREATIVE Cloneable CMS Template - Webflow](https://webflow.com/made-in-webflow/website/CREATIVE-Cloneable-CMS-Template)

I can’t figure out how the sliders are structured in the nav bar because I can’t seem to flip through them via the style bar.

Here’s a WIP preview of the website I’m working on: [Webflow - Enkayy LLC.](https://preview.webflow.com/preview/enkayy-llc?utm_medium=preview_link&utm_source=designer&utm_content=enkayy-llc&preview=68bd64eda7cfa890e06fb7bfe02d3b1f&workflow=preview)

In addition, I noticed that my page jitters even in preview mode. I was wondering if my deletion of elements changed the spacing as well? Is there a way I can track and keep it consistent?

Would appreciate the guidance